# Xamarin forms app no longer connected to easy tables

Tags: azure, ms-access, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have recently develop an Xamarin forms app which was linked to Microsoft Azure easy tables.  This is a B2B app and will only be used by half a dozen users. It has been approved by the App Store. The syncing with the easy tables worked great.

My client is very familiar with Microsoft Access, and wished to be able to view the tables and add/edit data via this software.  I successfully set up the express server and using ODBC linked the database to Access.  With no problems on that end.  I can see the data, delete rows and add/edit data.

But when I checked the app, the sync to the easy tables was hanging.  And when I went into Azure.  The easy tables are listed but they have no columns or data.

Are the easy tables now defunct because I have used ODBC to access them? Are they now different somehow?

How do I fix this?  Is there a different connection I need to use?  Do I need to set up a web api now?    Do I need to use a different Nuget package/code? I am just not sure which direction I need to head.

The data is still there as I can see it in Microsoft Access.

Or do I just cut my losses and recreate the database and a new set of easy tables?  There is not a lot of data to recreate and I have them in CSV files.

If this is the case, what is the best way of my client accessing and adding or editing the data from Azure? I realise the obvious one is developing a mobile app for him.  I just wanted to check if there is any other way?

Thanks

Comment: If the easy tables have no columns or data any more, then it might be possible that the ODBC connection to the SQL server, changed something that corrupted it. It has 4 columns that must be on each table to sync. [version], updatedAt, createdAt, deleted. I would make sure they all exist and don't have any odd data in them. Otherwise the only other thing I could think of is if the ODBC connection is locking the tables as it views them. I would try stopping the connection, waiting a bit then seeing if the sync works. If it still hangs, we would need more information on the exact part it hangs

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for assisting me.  Your advice, although did not directly solve the problem.  It sent me down a rabbit hole of looking at the data in the actual SQL Database, and when I was there it asked me to login.  I remembered I had changed the password to the server, when I was setting up the database in Microsoft Access as I could not not remember the original one (rookie mistake and I should know better).  I changed the password back (as I found it in the connection string).  Both now work.  Thanks again.